# Why i cant add to List in onResponse function

Tags: json, list, kotlin, jsonresponse

firstly sorry for grammar mistakes,

I am trying to create users with the information in my json url. I can get the all the information but when i try to add it to my list in OnResponse, it doesnt add. I log it if i get the data from url and it logs the information so there is no problem in getting the information. Hope you understood my question. Here is my code

My json file

```
{"User":[{"name":"Kaan","number":"1"},{"name":"Ertürk","number":"2"}]}
```

My User Data Class

```
    data class User(var name: String, var Id:String)
```

Here is my UserService class and a function in it to get the information from json

```
    fun getUser(url: URL) : MutableList<User>{
        var userList = mutableListOf<User>()
        var client =OkHttpClient()
        var urlFun = url
        var request = Request.Builder().url(urlFun).build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response){
                if (response.isSuccessful){
                    var myResponse = response?.body?.string()
                    var jsonObject = JSONObject(myResponse)
                    var jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("User")

                    for (item in 0 until jsonArray.length()){
                        var user = jsonArray.getJSONObject(item)
                        var nameUser = user.getString("name")
                        var numberUser = user.getString("number")
                        Log.e("Created User: ", User(nameUser,numberUser).toString())                    
                        userList.add(User("$nameUser","$numberUser"))
                    }

                }
            }

        })

        userList.add(User("123","123"))
        Log.e("UserServiceUserListSize" , userList.size.toString())
        return userList
    }


}
```

adding the User with the name 123 is working and userList size is 1.

And my MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        var url = URL("https://api.npoint.io/7f4353a444be404533f4")
        var userService = UserService().getUser(url)
        for (item in 0 until userService.size){
            var userName = userService[item].name
            var userId = userService[item].Id
            binding.textView.append("Name: $userName , ID: $userId \n")
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The callbacks of that enqueue call are executed asynchronously. So your code doesn't do what you'd expect on first sight. The function `onResponse()` will be executed *after* the function `getUser()` returns (as that is executed synchronously), meaning it won't be taken into account for the binding.textView stuff.

I'm not familiar with android (nor httpOk), so I don't know if this is the recommended way to do this, but it looks to me like the easiest solution is to move `binding.textView.append("Name: $userName , ID: $userId \n")` inside the onResponse part.

Alternatively you could use a synchronous http GET, but that would probably block your UI, so you most likely won't want that.